# Intelligent type conversion in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, types, converters

I have been playing around with converting a string to a value type in .NET, where the resulting value type is unknown. The problem I have encountered in my code is that I need a method which accepts a string, and uses a "best fit" approach to populate the resulting value type. Should the mechanism not find a suitable match, the string is returned.

This is what I have come up with:

```
public static dynamic ConvertToType(string value)
{
    Type[] types = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(System.SByte),
        typeof(System.Byte), 
        typeof(System.Int16), 
        typeof(System.UInt16), 
        typeof(System.Int32), 
        typeof(System.UInt32), 
        typeof(System.Int64), 
        typeof(System.UInt64), 
        typeof(System.Single), 
        typeof(System.Double), 
        typeof(System.Decimal),
        typeof(System.DateTime),
        typeof(System.Guid)
    };
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
         try
         {
               return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             continue;
         }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I feel that this approach is probably not best practice because it can only match against the predefined types.

Usually I have found that .NET accommodates this functionality in a better way than my implementation, so my question is: are there any better approaches to this problem and/or is this functionality implemented better in .NET?

**EDIT:** Note that the ordering of types in the array is so that the "best fit" occurs as accurately as possible for the given types.

**EDIT:** as per miniBill's request, this I how the method might be used (simple example!):

```
JsonDictionary["myKey"] = ConvertToType("255"); // 255 is a stringified json value, which should be assigned to myKey as a byte.
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the returned value?

Comment: @miniBill, As this is just a general helper function...anything! - for example, parsing stringified JSON values to known (System) value types.

Comment: My point is: dynamic is just a nice name for object, so when you actually use it you need to make sure it has a right type. Besides, it's not always obvious what the type of an object is. Think about: null, "", "null", "0", "-", ".", ...

Comment: Not that it is a big list, but I'd think of moving your `types` array outside of the method so you don't have to recreate the same array every time through this method.

Comment: @miniBill, the reason I used dynamic was to prevent casting, every time the method was to be used, however if using dynamic comes at a greater performance cost, I will change it.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Thanks I see what you mean. That would certainly improve the implementation somewhat. I have another implementation where you can pass in a custom array of types, thus intelligently parsing based on user selected types.

Comment: @series0ne, no dynamic is not a significant performance cost, what I meant was: do you have any point in your software where you are going to use this method or is it just a nice idea?

Comment: @miniBill, both! My software is a library, so the aim is that it will accommodate some requirements elsewhere in the library, and should also provide accommodation should other developers need it.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you use this method?

Comment: Are the stings your passing in fully qualified class names (System.String) or just simple (String)? are the types you have in your array the only types, or do you want to support any type?

Comment: To minibill's point, will you know the type you are trying to cast too ahead of time?  For example, will you call `Int32 foo = ConvertToType("1");` or `dynamic foo = ConvertToType("1");`

Comment: @miniBill, see end of question for example.

Comment: @psubsee2003, no, you might not necessarily know what the resulting type is. Otherwise I would just use System.Convert.ToXXXX(). The point here is that it should intelligently convert the string to the nearest known system type.

Comment: Fair enough, but have you considered the fact that if you try to parse a `GUID`, you are going to throw **12** exceptions before it finds the correct type.  That is going to be the biggest issue with performance.  I think you need to rethink your design?

Comment: @psubsee2003, exactly my point...there must be a better way to do this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method isn't ideal as its going to cause a series of exceptions if `value` is not a `SByte`.

Seeing as all of these types share a common method `.TryParse(string, out T)` we can use reflection extract the method and call it for each type. I made the method an extension method on `string` and also factored out the `Type[]` array into its own lazy loaded property for faster use.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static dynamic ConvertToType(this string value)
    {
        foreach (Type type in ConvertibleTypes)
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var methodParameterTypes = new Type[] { typeof(string), type.MakeByRefType() };
            var method = type.GetMethod("TryParse", methodParameterTypes);
            var methodParameters = new object[] { value, obj };

            bool success = (bool)method.Invoke(null, methodParameters);

            if (success)
            {
                return methodParameters[1];
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static Type[] _convertibleTypes = null;

    private static Type[] ConvertibleTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if (_convertibleTypes == null)
            {
                _convertibleTypes = new Type[]
                {
                    typeof(System.SByte),
                    typeof(System.Byte), 
                    typeof(System.Int16), 
                    typeof(System.UInt16), 
                    typeof(System.Int32), 
                    typeof(System.UInt32), 
                    typeof(System.Int64), 
                    typeof(System.UInt64), 
                    typeof(System.Single), 
                    typeof(System.Double), 
                    typeof(System.Decimal),
                    typeof(System.DateTime),
                    typeof(System.Guid)
                };
            }
            return _convertibleTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string value = "2391203921";
dynamic converted = value.ConvertToType();
```

Comment: I like this, its neat and covers all angles! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would work but, as you say, it's not that elegant.

I think you have a couple of ways to improve this code:

1. Move the array out of the function, as psubsee2003 said
2. Use the `TryParse` methods for cheaper testing (no catching involved) [(e.g.: `Int32.TryParse`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)
3. Actually write a parser that, after trimming,

   - Checks if the number is a GUID

     - Does it have '-' in it at a position > 0?
     - if(`Guid.TryParse`)

       - return result
     - return string (it can't be a number!)
   - Checks if the number is fractional (does it have a dot in it?)

     - Tries to convert to single, double, decimal using the various `TryParse`
     - If it fails return string
   - Does it start with a minus?

     - Try and parse as Int64, then check size and see where if fits (<256 -> ubyte, < 65536 ushort...)
     - If it fails return string
   - Try and parse as Int64

     - If it works check minimum size it fits into
     - If it fails it could be an integer, but too big, try parsing as double, if it fails return string

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrote previously that might be a help:

```
public static Boolean CanCovertTo(this String value, Type type)
{
    var targetType = type.IsNullableType() ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) : type;

    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
    return converter.IsValid(value);
}
```

The basic idea is if you pass the string and a `Type` that you want to test, you can check if a conversion will be valid before attempting to covert.

The problem with this design is that `TypeConverter.IsValid()` is just a wrapper (with some exception handling) for `TypeConverter.CanConvertFrom()` so you really aren't eliminating the exception handling, but since it is part of the BCL, I tend to think that is going to be a better implementation.

So you can implement this like so:

```
private static Type[] defaultTypes = new Type[]
{
    typeof(System.SByte),
    typeof(System.Byte), 
    typeof(System.Int16), 
    typeof(System.UInt16), 
    typeof(System.Int32), 
    typeof(System.UInt32), 
    typeof(System.Int64), 
    typeof(System.UInt64), 
    typeof(System.Single), 
    typeof(System.Double), 
    typeof(System.Decimal),
    typeof(System.DateTime),
    typeof(System.Guid)
};

public static dynamic ConvertToType(string value)
{
    return ConvertToType(value, defaultTypes);
}

public static dynamic ConvertToType(string value, Type[] types)
{
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        if (!value.CanConvertTo(type))
            continue;
        return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }

    return value;
}
```

There is not really a great way to do this without the exception handling (even the exception handling in the `TypeConverter.IsValid` method), so you have to live with it if you really need such a method.  But you can limit the need for the exception handling if you implement some of the suggestions in [miniBill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174001/250725) in addition to some improvements in the design.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Reflection` to handle all the `Parse` types by calling the `TryParse` method, this will be a bit faster than handling multiple exceptions using `ChangeType`

```
public Type[] PredefinedTypes = new Type[]
{
    typeof(System.SByte),
    typeof(System.Byte), 
    typeof(System.Int16), 
    typeof(System.UInt16), 
    typeof(System.Int32), 
    typeof(System.UInt32), 
    typeof(System.Int64), 
    typeof(System.UInt64), 
    typeof(System.Single), 
    typeof(System.Double), 
    typeof(System.Decimal),
    typeof(System.DateTime),
    typeof(System.Guid)
};


public dynamic ConvertToType(string value)
{
    foreach (var predefinedType in PredefinedTypes.Where(t => t.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name.Equals("TryParse"))))
    {
        var typeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(predefinedType);
        var methodParamTypes = new Type[] { typeof(string), predefinedType.MakeByRefType() };
        var methodArgs = new object[] { value, typeInstance };
        if ((bool)predefinedType.GetMethod("TryParse", methodParamTypes).Invoke(predefinedType, methodArgs))
        {
            return methodArgs[1];
        }
    }
    return value
}
```